# How to disown a chromium or chrome app on double click

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, google-chrome, chromium

I wrote a bash script to open an app (by double click) in my chromium. The code works but after opening the app when i close terminal the app also closes. I have searched through web and found out **nohup**, **disown** and **&** commands  and tried it on my bash script but nothing works can you tell me what is happening

This will open the app

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/chromium-browser --disable-gpu --enable-offline-auto-reload --enable-offline-auto-reload-visible-only --app=chrome-extension://jbnkffmindojffecdhbbmekbmkkfpmjd/foreground.html
```

when i added `disown` to it the app is not even opening

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/chromium-browser --disable-gpu --enable-offline-auto-reload --enable-offline-auto-reload-visible-only --app=chrome-extension://jbnkffmindojffecdhbbmekbmkkfpmjd/foreground.html & disown
```

Comment: "I wrote a bash script to open an app (by double click)", does this mean   you're running the script from a `.dektop` file?

Comment: Also if so, please add the `Exec=` line from the `.desktop` file

Comment: its not a `.desktop` file but a `.sh`. I made my bash script executable and changed the `behaviour` on nautilus to execute bash script instead of opening it

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:-

```
nohup /usr/bin/chromium-browser --disable-gpu --enable-offline-auto-reload --   enable-offline-auto-reload-visible-only --app=chrome-extension://jbnkffmindojffecdhbbmekbmkkfpmjd/foreground.html &
```

Is this what you wanted? Did it work for you?

Answer (score -1):

`disown` is a separate command you have run it on it's own. The best way to do so is to put it in an extra line:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/chromium-browser --disable-gpu --enable-offline-auto-reload --enable-offline-auto-reload-visible-only --app=chrome-extension://jbnkffmindojffecdhbbmekbmkkfpmjd/foreground.html & 
disown
```

Comment: still not working..app closes when terminal close

Comment: I tested it with `xclock` instead of chromium, it works fine. So either you are calling the script in a different way or there is something special in chromium.

Comment: `&` implicitly ends the previous command, so there's no need to put `disown` on the following line

Comment: K sorry i  forgot to add `& ` before but now i added `&` and `disown` . Now app is not even opening. Have you tried executing the bash script by double click?